# Call Back not running

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

My code :-

```
def load():
    label.configure(text="Error")
button = tkinter.Button(main,width=8,text="Continue >", command="load")
```

and the window is running perfectly but the callback is not running, I have tried many kind of callbacks like printing configuring etc. but didn't worked. What is solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `command` argument is expecting to have a function, Not a string.

Instead of string, use the the function.

Instead of:

```
button = tkinter.Button(main,width=8,text="Continue >", command="load")
```

write:

```
button = tkinter.Button(main,width=8,text="Continue >", command=load)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you passed load as a string .So it doesn't work. Because command in the sense what command should be performed when the component Button is clicked.
So try to change it  don't pass it as a string .

Change it as

```
button = tkinter.Button(main,width=8,text="Continue >", command=load)
```